# MySQL bug in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which has typographical error:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(qty) 
AS 
    'aqty1' 
FROM 
     po_details 
WHERE 
     product_id ='1196' 
AND 
     so_number = '1m';
```

It should be:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(qty) 
AS 
     'aqty1' 
FROM 
     po_details 
WHERE 
     product_id ='1196' 
AND 
     so_number = '1';
```

But the first wrong query which have `so_number = '1m'` mysteriously outputs correctly, the same output as the second correct query does, which should not be the case, right?

`product_id` and `so_number`'s data types are both `INT`. `so_number = '1m'` should've worked if `so_number`'s data type is `VARCHAR`, since I've enclosed the `1m` inside quotes, and the condition set was `so_number LIKE '%1m%'`.

So why is the above typo query works? Shouldn't MySQL error and says that it can't find the `1m` and consider it as `1`? Is this a known bug? I am using MySQL 5.6.14.

Here's a screenshot:

[image][image]

Comment: To compare MySQL has to convert `'1m'` to an integer. The best it can do is `1`.

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't read the character `m` even though I've enclosed them inside quotes?

Comment: Quotes are signifiers of strings, they're not meant to group things, like in online searches. If MySQL converts the string `'1m'` to an integer, which it has to do in order to compare it, it stops when it finds the non-numeric `'m'`, so it only finds the integer `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implicit conversion, performed by MySQL. You can read about that [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html):

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type
>   conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions
>   occur implicitly.

e.g.:

```
mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
        -> 2
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(2,' test');
        -> '2 test'
```

Comment: That's the explanation I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Implicit conversion is fine, but "partial conversion" of strings like '2m' can lead to unexpected results - the oracle DB throws an error in such cases. At least an unexpected behavior in MySQL, IMHO ...